# TensorFlow's sees.run with tensor input

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying to understand a TensorFlow code. In this program, the model is defined as

```
def fcn(x):
    ...
    return [out1, out2]
```

then, after training the model, and during evaluation,

```
z = sample(100)  # generate sample inputs
samples = sess.run(fcn(X), feed_dict={X: z})
samples[0] = np.argmax(samples[0], axis=2)
samples[1] = np.argmax(samples[1], axis=3)
samples[1] = sess.run(samples[1] - tf.matrix_band_part(samples[1],0,0))
```

My question is about `sess.run`. The first time we use this, we provide a model and it's input. In this case, it is intuitive that we should expect the model output. What I don't understand is the second time we use `sess.run`. What does it mean to input the modified output back into the `sess.run`? I couldn't figure it out by looking to the [official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/Session.Run).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the reason. If you have a more complete solution, don't hesitate to post it.

> The easiest way to evaluate the actual value of a
>   `Tensor` object is to pass it to the `Session.run()` method, or call
>   `Tensor.eval()` when you have a default session (i.e. in a `with
>   tf.Session():` block, or see below). In general, you
>   cannot print the value of a tensor without running some code in a
>   session.